# Service-oriented peer-to-peer market place tool (like Airbnb experience)?

Tags: e-commerce, marketplace

I know similar subjects had been posted but i did not find the answer to my concern. I would like to create a peer-to-peer market where people can book activity providers (at a certain time and date proposed by the seller - multiple people can book the same time slot). The best example in the place is Airbnb experience. Would you have tools to recommend in order to quickly set up an MVP? I am not an experienced coder, I would prefer a Saas platform or set up an ecommerce tool. I have tried Sharetribe but it does not fit my needs.

I’ve tried to benchmark similar startups in the place like:

- https://www.adrenaline-hunter.com
- www.yakaygo.com

These 2 examples seem to use similar ecommerce/market place platform but I cannot figure out what they are using (I tried with BuiltWith - Web Technology Profiler (http://builtwith.com) and Wappalyzer). Do you have an idea of which platform they are using and if it’s relevant to start fast?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fit your requirements : http://www.cocolabs.io/en